# Can one apply iOS Developer Program ($99/year) and iOS Developer Enterprise Program ($299/year) at the same time?

Tags: ios

From https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/enterprise/create.php I see this:

> You can enroll in the iOS Developer Enterprise Program with the same
>   Apple ID you use for other services like iCloud and the Apple Online
>   Store. However, if you are already enrolled in an Apple Developer
>   Program or have an iTunes Connect account for distributing another
>   media type (music, TV, movies, or books), you need to use a different
>   Apple ID for your enrollment.

It seems that people can't use the original Apple ID to enroll if having enrolling iOS Developer Program ($99/year). Is it necessary to use a new Apple ID?

How about D-U-N-S? Can two Apple IDs use the same D-U-N-S?

Comment: Now the enterprise account is not good to apply, many people do not have this kind of account, you can look at this website,https://www.iosenterpriseaccount.com/, 
the enterprise program in principle can let a lot of people(no limit) inside the company to use, while the iOS developer program can be published to the public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Its not possible.

If you are already registered for iOS Developer program then you want to go for the Enterprise program then you have to contact Apple for that. [Contact Apple](https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php)

If you are already registered for the iOS Enterprise program then you must have to setup new account for iOS developer program.

Q : I am already enrolled in the iOS Developer Enterprise Program. Can I add the iOS Developer Program to my existing account?

A : No. If you would like to distribute apps on the App Store, you must set up a new Apple ID to enroll in the [iOS Developer Program.](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/)

For more info refer [Program Enrollment](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enrollment.html)

Comment: It seems that one should setup a new account to apply iOS Enterprise Program if he has already  set up ios Developer Program, too.

Comment: Yes you are right.

**Q :** Can I use the Apple ID associated with my iOS Developer Program to join the iOS Developer Enterprise Program?

**A :** No. You must set up a new Apple ID to join the iOS Developer Enterprise Program.

For more info refer [Account Management](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.html)

Answer (score -3):

It is now possible to use the same Apple ID for both a normal developer account and an enterprise account! From the [latest Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingAccounts/ManagingAccounts.html):

> A single Apple ID can be associated with multiple Apple Developer Program accounts. Using the same Apple ID, you can enroll as an individual and join other teams. However, your Apple ID can only be associated with a single iTunes Connect account.

You still can't use the same Apple ID for two separate iTunes Connect accounts. But since Enterprise doesn't use iTunes Connect, you can safely use the same Apple ID for both!

Comment: "However, your Apple ID can only be associated with a single iTunes Connect account." this is not mentioned

Comment: @johnboiles You are talking about something else here. It is true that one Apple ID can be "associated" with different Apple Developer Program accounts. That means e.g. one developer can be invited to work for different teams. But, an Apple ID cannot itself join the developer program and the enterprise developer program at the same time. I've just talked with Apple about this, because we need both programs at our company. Apple told us that it is necessary to create two different Apple IDs - one for each program.